# How can i make an option selected with jquery-template

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-templates

I'm using jquery-template and i need make an option selected, according json's value.

Javascript:

```
$.ajax({ 
    type: 'POST',
    url: caminho + '/controller/ctrl_usuario.php',
    data: 'acao=buscarUsuarioPorId&idUsuario=' + id,
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function (response) {
        if (response.status == 1) {
            //$('.cadastro').append(response.dados);

          $("#" + id).loadTemplate(caminho + "cadastro/form-usuario.php", response.dados, {error: function (e) {
                    console.log(e);
                }});
        }
    },
    complete: function () {
        //code
    }
});
```

json returned:
"dados":[{"nome":"Maria Silva","l_Sexo":"F"}]"

```
    <div class="wrp-inp">
        <label for="genero">Gênero:</label>
        <span class="icon-chevron-down"></span>
        <select name="genero" id="genero" >
            <option value="M" {{if l_Sexo == 'M'}}selected{{/if}}>Male</option>
            <option value="F" {{if l_Sexo == 'F'}}selected{{/if}}>Female</option>
        </select>
    </div>
```

The sample above didn't work.

Comment: what didnt work? what is in the console log?

Comment: Hi @Harry! There is no console error. But the option didn't stay selected. The jquery template load all json data in my html template. But i didn't find a way to set the selected value in jquery-template library

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just do:

```
var value = 'M';
$('select[name="genero"]').val(value);
```

Answer (score 0):

The complete Solution:

Javascript:

```
$.ajax({ 
    type: 'POST',
    url: caminho + '/controller/ctrl_usuario.php',
    data: 'acao=buscarUsuarioPorId&idUsuario=' + id,
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function (response) {
        if (response.status == 1) {

           $("#" + id).loadTemplate(caminho + "cadastro/form-usuario.php", response.dados, {error: function (e) {
                    console.log(e);
                }});

            var sexo = response.dados[0].l_Sexo; 
            $("#genero").val(sexo);
        }
    },
    complete: function () {
        //code
    }
});
```

HTMl:

```
    <div class="wrp-inp">
        <label for="genero">Gênero:</label>
        <span class="icon-chevron-down"></span>
        <select name="genero" id="genero" >
           <option value="M">Masculino</option>
           <option value="F">Feminino</option>
        </select>
    </div>
```